# Rename with a "/" in the name

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, rename, batch-rename, escape-characters

I am trying to change a `@` in the name to `/` for multiple files using `cmd`'s `ren` command but couldn't as "/" is an identifier.
None of the below worked...
1. `ren TODAY@WEEK TODAY/WEEK`
2. `ren TODAY@WEEK "TODAY/WEEK"`
3. `ren TODAY@WEEK TODAY^/WEEK`

Answer (score 2):

In Windows command line the slash symbol `/` is an option symbol. So when you execute, for example, `ren TODAY@WEEK TODAY/WEEK` then it is treated as a command `ren` with option `/WEEK` and parameters `TODAY@WEEK TODAY`. I.e. it is equal to `ren /WEEK TODAY@WEEK TODAY`. This cause "wrong command option" or similar error message.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. +1 for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what kind of quoting or escaping you use in Cmd; that's not where the problem lies.

Slash `/` is not allowed in names, because it is a path separator in the same way that `\` is. Although Windows traditionally uses backslash, it recognizes both characters as special, so if you had "TODAY/WEEK 2", then "TODAY" would be considered a folder name and not part of the filename.

So the only way to make this possible is to create a *folder* named "TODAY". Then "TODAY/WEEK" will refer to a file named "WEEK".

Comment: so is there an alternate way i can get to it ? I definitely need "/" in the names for a project

Comment: The **only** way that's possible is to create a _folder_ named `TODAY`, then `TODAY/WEEK` will become simply a file named "WEEK".

Comment: You can also get other Unicode characters which look kinda similar to a "/" (for example U+2215 `∕` or U+2571 `╱` or U+FF0F `／` or U+29F8 `⧸`), but you cannot get the actual U+002F `/` in the middle of a filename – that restriction is set in stone.

Comment: Actually / is not a path separator but a commandline switch. Only in unix/linux type of OSses is / a path separator, and in web url's (which stems from unix). That said, it still is one of the chars that you cannot use in the filename, so that part is correct. Windows explorer is smart enough to understand that / could be a path, but commandline won't. So part of your answer is actually incorrect.

Comment: @LPChip: It's accepted as a path separator in the Win32 API, in the sense that it's treated the same way as `\\` when resolving regular file paths, as documented at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation So if you go outside Cmd, you can use paths like "c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe" practically everywhere.

Comment: @grawity yes, I am fully aware. Given the question is about cmd, that invalidates your answer IMHO

Comment: @LPChip: It doesn't; Cmd is built on the Win32 API and follows the same rules. The slash is only interpreted by commands as an option char if it's the *first* character in that word; when used in the middle of a parameter it becomes a regular part of the path: https://i.imgur.com/0RIMUc2.png

Comment: (The only places it doesn't work is certain Cmd built-ins which have their own argument parser which ignores even quoting, such as `DEL` or `TYPE`, because of course none of them are consistent with each other.)